# I was creating a carousel which displays trending cryptoCurrencys using AliceCarousel but the output is not correct

Tags: reactjs, carousel

picture of the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kxvb.png

code of the carousel

import React from 'react'
import AliceCarousel from 'react-alice-carousel';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import UseAxios from '../hooks/UseAxios'
import "./Trending.css";

const Trending = () => {

```
const { response } = UseAxios("search/trending");

return (
```

```
 {response && response.coins.map(coin => {
         return <div className='flex slide' key={coin.item.coin_id}>

             <Link to={`/coin/${coin.item.id}`}>
                 <div>
                    <AliceCarousel 
                    mouseTracking
                    infinite
                    autoPlayInterval={1000}
                    animationDuration={1500}
                    disableButtonsControls
                    autoPlay
                    >
                     <img src={coin.item.large} className="mt-0 relative top-30 img" />
                     <p key={coin.item.coin_id} className="name"> {coin.item.name}  </p>
                     </AliceCarousel>
                 </div>
             </Link>

         </div>
     })}
 </div>
```

```
)
```

}

export default Trending;
note:- library being used is AliceCarousel.
can someone please help me fix the carousel.

Comment: you should format your question to be more intuitive and also state clearly what your expected output is.

Comment: looks like you want a Carousel holds multiple images/links. so the order from outter to inner is `AliceCarousel -> response.coins.map -> Link -> image`

Comment: hey, it's working perfectly thank you so much for your help:)

I had a question I'm just starting out in the development space could you please tell me how were you able to think about the solution? I mean your mindset to arrive at the solution as to how were you able to figure out that this has to be the right answer

Comment: about this question, I have used Carousel so I know the common way to make it work. And the generic way to come up with a solution is similar to that too: you learn, read docs, then practise exercises, if encounter issues, find solution in docs first, then finds in forums. Just repeat those things over years.